# Activity to slide to bottom while the activity being loaded stays (as if it slides down to reveal new activity)

Tags: java, android, animation, transition

Having some problems with this transition. It is the only transition that does not work. On the main screen of my application, there is a settings icon in the action bar. When clicked, the settings activity slides to the top (over the main screen, the main screen activity just stays put). This works fine.

In the settings activity there is an accept icon in the action bar. When clicked, I want the settings activity to slide to the bottom (back down and revealing the main activity which again, does not slide). At the moment, when I click the accept icon, no transition takes place. It just reveals the main activity with no transition at all. This is the code I have so far:

stay.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:duration="310"
     android:fromYDelta="0%p"
     android:toYDelta="0%p" />
</set>
```

slide_out_top.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:duration="300" 
     android:fromYDelta="100%"
     android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

slide_in_top.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:duration="300" 
     android:fromYDelta="100%"
     android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me and has the same behaviour as you describe.
The Main Activity stays below the Settings activity, while the SettingsActivity slides from bottom to top upon creation.

And vice versa. The SettingsActivity slides down (revealing the MainActivity below), when finishing

no_change.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="700"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="0" />

    <alpha
        android:duration="700"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />

</set>
```

push_up.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="700"
        android:fromYDelta="100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0" />

    <alpha
        android:duration="700"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />

</set>
```

push_down.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="700"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="100%p" />

    <alpha
        android:duration="700"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />

</set>
```

MainActivity.java

```
//somewhere in your code where the Settings activity is started
MainActivity.this.startActivity( new Intent( MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class ) );
overridePendingTransition( R.anim.push_up, R.anim.no_change );
```

SettingsActivity.java

```
// somewhere in your code where the Settings Activity is finished
finish();
overridePendingTransition( R.anim.no_change, R.anim.push_down );
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried this code and it's still not transitioning properly. The main activity literally just appears. This code works for you? I can't think of anything that could be getting in the way.

Comment: @caffro yes, this works for me, here a very short screencast: https://www.dropbox.com/s/y6jdadidtucxv5w/animation.mov

Maybe, you can share some more info, like: how exactly do you call your activities? Did you change the transition duration? What Android version?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the transition I'm looking for. When the settings icon is pressed in the action bar it calls the method "jumpToSettings()". Inside this method is the intent, start intent and finally overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_up,R.anim.stay). Inside the settings activity is the exact same code, except it loads the main activity and uses the pushes down animation. I changed the transition duration to 300 on all animations. Min. SDK is 14 and target SDK is 19.

Comment: all this sounds good.  I have min SDK 8 and target 19. Do you test on a device or in the emulator? Do you have some flags/settings in the manifest file for these activities?

Comment: I test the application on my Nexus 4. This is my Main and Settings activities in the Android Manifest file [link](http://pastebin.com/M5BQRqgK)